# In order to observe a structure of length order of 1 femtometer, how large kinetic energy must the electron have?

Tags: particle-physics, wavelength

According to the de Broglie relation, $\lambda=h/p$ where $h$ is the (not reduced) Planck Constant and $p$ is the magnitude of the relativistic 3-momentum. So, it should be that $\lambda$ should be the order of $10^{-15}\,\mathrm{m}$. Thus, the electron's 3 momentum must have the magnitude of about $4.135\,\mathrm{eV\cdot s \cdot m^{-1}}$. Using the relation $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$, I obtain $E=1240.5\,\mathrm{MeV}$. Since the rest energy of an electron is about $0.511\,\mathrm{MeV}$. I conclude that the electron must have the kinetic energy of $1240\,\mathrm{MeV}$. Is my calculation correct?

Comment: what is $\hbar c$? All experimentalist have this memorized.

Comment: Why should I use the reduced Planck Constant? Isn't $h$ what should be used?

Comment: $E = \hbar \omega $. Scratch that: $p = \hbar k$, and $p$ is the conjugate variable to position.

Comment: BTW particle physicist have long since figured out how to make life easy on themselves. According to my copy of the *Particle Physics Booklet*, $\hbar c = 197 \,\mathrm{MeV\,fm}$, which (after you stick that pesky factor of $2\pi$ back in leads to ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

We can also use the more direct method of $E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$ to obtain the answer.

Comment: I think that formula applies to only photons. My calculation is for electrons.

Comment: @Keith: That formula applies to electrons as well. The only condition is that it is a free particle.

Comment: Why? The formula implies that the particle has speed of the light